# PHP: Display comma seperated list with <a href=''> anchor tags

Tags: php

I am using this code to display a comma seperated list but removing the last comma.

how can i add a link (`a href`) to each item displayed?

```
$tags = explode(',', $ret["tags"]);
echo join(' , ', array_filter(
        array_merge(
            array(
                join(', ', array_slice($tags, 0, -1))
            ), array_slice($tags, -1)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: sometimes verbose is better

Comment: can you show how you are converting your comma separated string into array?

Comment: why `join` if you're just going to wrap that string in another array?

Comment: why all the looping if you just need to remove the last comma from a string? Why not just do a simple `rtrim($string, ",")`, and then parse it into array if needed.

Comment: someone else wrote this code for me - i basically want to display each word along with a link. so if i have a, b, c i want to show it as a, b, c but each one with a link

Comment: the some one elsse must got paid by the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would redo your code:

```
$tags = "link1,link2,link3,link4,";
$tags = rtrim($tags, ","); // remove last comma
$tags = explode(',', $tags); // turns to array
foreach($tags as $tag){ // iterate 
    $arr[] = "<a href='$tag'>$tag<a>"; //turn it into link
}
$final = implode(",",$arr); //turn it back to string
echo $final;
```